# What is the interpretation/intuition of $e^{itA}$ for a self-adjoint unbounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $A : i \frac{d}{dt} : D(A) \to H^1([0,1])$ with domain $D(A)=H^1_*([0,1])=\{u \in H^1([0,1]): u(0)=u(1)\} \subseteq H^1([0,1])$. Then I know that $A$ is self-adjoint. Using the spectral theorem, we find that for any $u \in L^2([0,1])$, an explicit formula for $(e^{itA}u)(x,t)$ is given by $\tilde{u}(x,t)= u(x-t)$. This makes sense to me, because $\tilde{u}$ satisfies the PDE $\ \partial_t \tilde{u} = -\partial_x \tilde{u}$ with initial condition $u$, which is what one finds when formally taking the following derivative : $$ \partial_t (e^{itA}u) = iA (e^{itA}u) = -\partial_x (e^{itA}u).$$

Now, I have trouble understanding the following. If we take $A_{\alpha}: i \frac{d}{dt} : D(A_\alpha) \to H^1$ this time with domain $D(A_\alpha) = \{u \in H^1([0,1]) : u(0)=e^{i\alpha}u(1)\}$, then $A_\alpha$ is also self-adjoint. With the spectral theorem, we find $(e^{itA_\alpha}u)(x,t)= u(x-t)e^{-i \alpha t},$ which this time satisfies the PDE $\partial_t \tilde{u} + \partial_x \tilde{u} = -i\alpha \tilde{u}.$ But in my opinion, this contradicts the intuition provided by the formal derivative (which hasn't changed) : $$ \partial_t (e^{itA}u) = iA (e^{itA}u) = -\partial_x (e^{itA}u). $$
So we see that even though we have taken the "same" operator $A \sim A_{\alpha}$, the PDE solved by applying $e^{itA}$ has changed, just by changing the domain of definition of the operator and the formal derivation doesn't work (at least the same way) anymore.

I thought the point of $e^{itA}$ was just to solve the 'heat equation' $\partial_t \tilde{u} = iA \tilde{u}$ ? What is an interpretation of this phenomenon ? Is there a way to know what domain we should work on if we are given a specific PDE to 'solve' ?

Comment: Can you explain how we get $(e^{itA_{\alpha}}u)(x,t)=u(x-t)e^{-i\alpha t}$?

Comment: Define $U: (Uf)(x)=e^{-i\alpha x} f(x)$. Then $U$ is a unitary isomorphism $D(A_\alpha) \to D(A)$. From $U A_\alpha U^{-1} f = i \partial_x f - \alpha f$ we see that $A_\alpha$ is unitarily equivalent to $i \partial_x - \alpha$ on $H^1(S^1)$ (the unit circle). Using the Fourier transform we diagonalise $A_\alpha$ to pointwise multiplication $(a_n) \to ((-n-\alpha)a_n )$. Finally, use the inverse Fourier transform to find $f(x-t)e^{-i\alpha t}$.

Comment: Careful here. The PDEs you are solving are transport equations, not heat equations.